# Episode of cover to cover- John Robbins. Book used?

Tags: art, illustrated-story

I'd like to know if anyone remembers an episode of the PBS series 'Cover to Cover' with John Robbins in which he illustrated a story where a rabbit sought to gain antlers like a deer; the rabbit attached some antlers he found by fixing them to his head with wax.  I saw this when I was very young and I would like to know what fantasy story or book he was illustrating; Robbins' illustrations were haunting.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because [talking animals do not make a work on-topic on SFF](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5117/are-anthropomorphic-animals-by-themselves-enough-to-deem-a-work-fantasy). This would, however, likely be on-topic on Literature:SE if you were certain that it was based on a reading of a book.

Comment: I don't recall that the animals talked at all.

Comment: That doesn't improve matters ;-)

Comment: The book was a fantasy- I'm hoping someone might remember it.